# dispatch_get_global_queue set flags = 1 , the crash

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, exc-bad-access

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 1), ^{ 
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(listenNotification:) name:@"aysNofitication" object:nil];
    });
}
```

the code will crash when I set the flags 1.

the crash is : Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sermandurai Subbiah said, you simply should not use anything other than `0` for the flags parameter of `dispatch_get_global_queue`. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452927-dispatch_get_global_queue?language=occ) for `dispatch_get_global_queue` clearly warns us:

> Flags that are reserved for future use. Always specify 0 for this parameter.